# How can I validate value in SOAP response in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, request

I'm working with WSDL endpoint. And I'm fairly new to SOAP clients and I've hit a road block with some of the values integrating with the XML.

I have partial snippets that relates to the data I'm trying to pass. Below

```
    <s:element name="CreateLoan2">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Auth" type="tns:IntegrationAuthentication"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Borrower" type="tns:ArrayOfBorrower"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Broker" type="tns:Broker"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Property" type="tns:ArrayOfProperty"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LenderCaseId" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LoanOfficerId" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EntityName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PrePaymentPenaltyMonths" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DealDescription" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Program" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LoanAmount" type="s:double"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestedCloseDate" nillable="true" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InterestRate" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TermMonths" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginationPoints" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="BrokerPoints" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InterestPaymentReservesType" type="tns:InterstReservesType"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PurchaseFundsDisbursedAtClosing" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RehabFundsDisbursedAtClosing" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="investorName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Holdback" type="s:double"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DrawInterestType" type="tns:DrawInterestType"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PointsRolled" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InterestReservesRolled" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Milestone" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TriMergeCreditScore" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LastPulledCreditDate" nillable="true" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LONote" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RecentlyPreApproved" nillable="true" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ExitStrategy" nillable="true" type="tns:ExitStrategy"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReferralSource" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PlanToEscrowTaxesAndInsurance" nillable="true" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OtherPropertiesCurrentlyUnderContract" nillable="true"     type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CashAvailableToClose" nillable="true" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumberRehabsInLast6Months" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumberRehabsInLast12Months" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumberRehabsInLast24Months" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumberRehabsInLast60Months" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CurrentNumberRehabsInProgress" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ExistingHardPrivateMoneyLoansBalance" nillable="true"     type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MonthlyPaymentAmntExistingHardPrivateMoneyLoans" nillable="true"     type="s:decimal"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Further down we have

```
<s:simpleType name="InterstReservesType">
<s:restriction base="s:string">
<s:enumeration value="Percent"/>
<s:enumeration value="Months"/>
</s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

The error I'm experiencing is `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 617). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: 'Array' is not a valid value for InterstReservesType.`

My code is as follows

```
 $url = 'someservice.com/serviceprovider.asmx?WSDL';
 $soapclient = new soapClient($url);
 $param = array(
    'CustomerId'=>'1', 
    'IntegrationKey'=>'2erf13rsdfsdfsdfw2', 
    'LoanOfficerId'=>'21sdfs978',
    'PrePaymentPenaltyMonths'=>'2',
    'LoanAmount'=>'33200',
    'InterestRate'=>'3.45', 
    'TermMonths'=>'34',
    'OriginationPoints'=>'123',
    'BrokerPoints'=>'1254',
    'InterestPaymentReservesType'=> array('Percent'=>'1231', 'Months'=>'123'),
    'InterstReservesType'=>'sdfsd',
    'PurchaseFundsDisbursedAtClosing'=>'123123.11' ,
    'RehabFundsDisbursedAtClosing'=>'1232',
    'Holdback'=>'123',
    'DrawInterestType'=>'',
    'PointsRolled'=>'',
    'InterestReservesRolled'=>'',
    'Milestone'=>'',
    'TriMergeCreditScore'=>'',
    'LastPulledCreditDate'=>'',
    'LONote'=>'',
    'RecentlyPreApproved'=>'',
    'ExitStrategy'=>'',
    'ReferralSource'=>'',
    'PlanToEscrowTaxesAndInsurance'=>'',
    'OtherPropertiesCurrentlyUnderContract'=>'',
    'CashAvailableToClose'=>'',
    'NumberRehabsInLast6Months'=>'',
    'NumberRehabsInLast12Months'=>'',
    'NumberRehabsInLast24Months'=>'',
    'NumberRehabsInLast60Months'=>'',
    'CurrentNumberRehabsInProgress'=>'',
    'ExistingHardPrivateMoneyLoansBalance'=>'',
    'MonthlyPaymentAmntExistingHardPrivateMoneyLoans'=>''
    );
 $response = $soapclient->CreateLoan2($param);

 var_dump($response);

 $array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
 print_r($array);
 }catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo '</pre>';
 }
```

The idea is to submit the data to create a loan with the values retrieved from the form submission. Any help and any advice I would greatly appreciate it or if you need more info. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
<Borrower>
    <Borrower>
      <first_name>string</first_name>
      <middle_name>string</middle_name>
      <last_name>string</last_name>
      <primary_phone>string</primary_phone>
      <email>string</email>
      <ssn>string</ssn>
      <is_guarantor>boolean</is_guarantor>
      <lender_API_id>string</lender_API_id>
      <BorrowerResidenceOwnershipPaymentType>Mortgage or Rent or PaidOff or Other</BorrowerResidenceOwnershipPaymentType>
    </Borrower>
</Borrower>
```

Comment: I'd bet `InterstReservesType` is a typo. Even if not, it appears to be a data type, not an element.

Comment: @miken32 A typo on my end or the endpoint? What I found upon looking this up is it has to do with the enumeration field or type. But what I found was related to python and/or C# and I'm unable to translate that to PHP unfortunately.

Comment: It's irrelevant. It's shown in WSDL as `s:simpleType` and not `s:element` so it shouldn't be part of your request.

Comment: @miken32 did you see this `<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InterestPaymentReservesType" type="tns:InterstReservesType"/>` ? I don't know if it matters or not. I see what you are saying though.

Comment: That's saying that the `InterestPaymentReservesType` element accepts data in the form of `tns:InterstReservesType`.

Comment: @miken32 Ah ok, then that means the way I'm passing that data in my code is wrong then.

Comment: I think your `InterestPaymentReservesType` looks fine, but there's no such element as `InterstReservesType`; remove it.

Comment: @miken32 I fixed it! I realized I should've looked at the sample request in the documentation. Would by any chance how to push data to elements 2-3 layers in? for example: `<Borrower>    <Borrower><first_name>String</first_name><last_name>String></last_name></Borrower></Borrower>`. Would it be an array?

Comment: Just use nested arrays